# Issue connecting windows 7 slave to debian master on jenkins

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, webdriver, debian

I am trying to connect a windows slave to a linux master on jenkins and I always see the error below. I have tried everything that the link below mentions but I still see the same error.

> ```
> ERROR: Access is denied. See http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windows+slaves+fail+to+start+via+DCOM for more information about how to resolve this.
> org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Message not found for errorCode: 0x00000005   
>     at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.init(JIComServer.java:542)    
>     at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.initialise(JIComServer.java:458)
>     at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.<init>(JIComServer.java:427)
>     at org.jvnet.hudson.wmi.WMI.connect(WMI.java:59)    
>     at hudson.os.windows.ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.launch(ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.java:225)
>     at hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:200)   
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)   
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)     
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) 
> Caused by: rpc.FaultException: Received fault. (unknown)    
>     at rpc.ConnectionOrientedEndpoint.call(ConnectionOrientedEndpoint.java:142)
>     at rpc.Stub.call(Stub.java:112)     
>     at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.init(JIComServer.java:538)    
>     ... 10 more
> ```

Comment: Are you using an admin account from the master or the system account? Have you tried the registry hack mentioned in that link?

Comment: I am using the system account

Comment: And yes i did try the registry hack and i get the same error

Comment: I have had good luck setting up a dedicated admin account and then providing that in the Jenkins interface. You have to look at how that approach fits into your overall security architecture though.

Comment: I have some success now, i did some registry tweaking and the master linux box is now talking to the slave windows box. I still see this error ERROR: The service didn't respond. Perphaps it failed to launch?

Comment: This is the exact message - Checking if Java exists
java full version "1.6.0_32-b05"
Copying jenkins-slave.xml
Copying slave.jar
Starting the service
Waiting for the service to become ready
ERROR: The service didn't respond. Perphaps it failed to launch?

Comment: I am facing the same error.. but Windows Master and Windows slave. I have other windows slaves configured, so this proves, the problem has to be machine specific and Jenkins configuration is fine.

Comment: @Pulak Agrawal - Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: @Riv nope, just parked it for now. What I am doing as a workaround is calling a batch script which uses PSEXEC internally and logs on to the slave , then executes my build.

Answer (score 8):

1. Launch 'regedit.exe' as 'Administrator'
2. Find the following registry key: 'HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{76A64158-CB41-11D1-8B02-00600806D9B6}'
3. Right click and select 'Permissions'
4. Press 'Advanced'
5. Double click on Administrators
6. Allow Full Control
7. Restart Remote Registry Service

**UPDATE:** As mentioned by **@Kobi** in comments,

> If you cannot change the permissions, you need to first [change the
>   owner](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/access-denied-setting-owner-andor-permissions-on/71cdd66a-75ce-4e79-bace-89637e0dacae?auth=1) of this registry path, under "Advanced > Owner".

A step by step instructions on changing ownership can be found [here](http://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-take-ownership-permission-of-a-registry-key-in-windows/).

Comment: Note: if you cannot change the permissions, you need to first [change the **owner**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-update/access-denied-setting-owner-andor-permissions-on/71cdd66a-75ce-4e79-bace-89637e0dacae?auth=1) of this registry path, under "Advanced > Owner".

Comment: @Kobi 's answer should be upvoted more than it is! Thanks kobi.